# npx create-react-app <name> stops running after a certain part

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have never faced this issue with the good old

`create-react-app`

but this time I use the

`npx create-react-app`

to create a react app. this is the screenshot of the progress. It stops right there.

[image]

Information:
Node v10.16.3
NPM v6.13.6
Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have installed `create-react-app` globally.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my NPM Cache or the whole NPM is corrupted. I have to uninstall and delete manually the cache inside

> Users/User/AppData/Roaming

to make sure no package is installed globally. After that I reinstall Node JS and everything works exactly as expected.